Objects are displayed below the form field drowdown
I have created a form which is creating a new object of a model in which there is one field which is dropdown as it is a foreign key in model but the objects are also displayed below the field along with the dropdown.
Image 
Model:
class VehicleType(models.Model):
    model = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    farekm = models.FloatField()
    capacity = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.model


class Vehicle(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(VehicleType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.number

View:
def request_cabbie_upgrade(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        vehicle_form = VehicleForm(request.POST)
        if vehicle_form.is_valid():
            vehicle = vehicle_form.save(commit=False)
            vehicle.save()
            cabbie_request = CabbieRequest(user=request.user, vehicle=vehicle)
            cabbie_request.save()
            return redirect('PassengerDashboard')
    else:
        vehicle_form = VehicleForm()
    return render(request, 'users/cabbie_request.html', {'vehicle_form': vehicle_form, 'user': request.user})

Form:
class VehicleForm(forms.ModelForm):

    type = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=VehicleType.objects.all(), empty_label="Vehicle Type")

    class Meta:
        model = Vehicle
        fields = ['type', 'number']

Template:
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}
<title>Cabbie Dashboard</title>
{% endblock title %}
{% block body %}
<div class="container mt-5 pt-5 cabbie-dashboard-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h2>Cabbie Information</h2>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p><strong>Username:</strong> {{ cabbie.username }}</p>
          <p><strong>First Name:</strong> {{ cabbie.first_name }}</p>
          <p><strong>Last Name:</strong> {{ cabbie.last_name }}</p>
          <p><strong>Email:</strong> {{ cabbie.email }}</p>
          <p><strong>Phone:</strong> {{ cabbie.phone }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 mt-4">
      <h2>Request Cabbie Upgrade</h2>
      <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="id_type">Vehicle Type:</label>
          {{ vehicle_form.type }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="id_number">Vehicle Number:</label>
          {{ vehicle_form.number }}
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Request</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock body %}


I was expecting it just to be dropdown there.

Can you explain what you mean by "but the objects are also displayed below the field along with the dropdown".  Perhaps an image.  Also, can you edit your question with the VehicleType class.

By the objects I meant that the data present in the models which has to show in the dropdown are also showing explicitly. Like this:
Vehicle Type: Vehicle Type(This is the dropdown)
Vehicle Type
Vehicle Type
Sedan
The below are the options which also can be use to select but I do not want that.

If I understand your question correctly, the issue is that you have to define a __str__ function for your models so that Django knows what to display in the dropdown list:
# models.py

class VehicleType(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.type}'
    


class Vehicle(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(VehicleType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.number}: {self.type.type}'

Edit
I tried to reproduce your problem, but could not:
First picture

Second picture


I have tried that later on but still it is same:
`class VehicleType(models.Model):
model = models.CharField(max_length=50)
farekm = models.FloatField()
capacity = models.IntegerField()
def __str__(self):
    return self.model

class Vehicle(models.Model):
type = models.ForeignKey(VehicleType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
def __str__(self):
    return self.number`


I tried to reproduce the problem, @AsmitKumar but could not, as you can see from the pictures.  Perhaps you have JavaScript or your base.html is adding something I do not see.  If you do figure out the issue, let me know.

Yes you are right, the problem lies somewhere in base.html.

I had a nice select funtion in my js.$(document).ready(function () {   $('select').niceSelect();  }); It was causing the problem. Now it is resolved
